# MySQL: Iteratively insert a record if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a huge table like this,

```
user_id    item     value
      1      aa         1
      1      bb         0
      1      cc         0
      2      aa         1
      2      bb         1
      2      cc         1
      2     xxx         1
      3      aa         0
      3      bb         0
      3      cc         0
    ...     ...       ...
```

I want to insert a record like this

```
{user_id}     xxx     0
```

for all the users if they don't have this 'xxx' record. Is it possible to do this in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics of what you are asking for are suitable for an `NOT EXISTS` check, to start you off, you can select the user's who do not have that entry as follows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u1.user_id
FROM yourUserTable u1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourUserTable u2 WHERE u2.item='xxx' and u2.user_id = u1.user_id)
```

From that you can then construct your insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO youUserTable (user_id, item, value)
SELECT etc
```

If there was a unique key on the user_id / item then there are some alternative options.